# Before Fully Connected Layer in Tensorflow size of image become 7*7*64

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am a new in tensorflow network.While I am going through the code that is available in tensorflow documentation I found a line--

```
#Densely Connected Layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
```

I came to know that the 7*7*64 is the size of the image before applying it to the fully connected layer.But I cannot understand how the size of the image reduces from 28*28 to 7*7.
And what is 1024 and from where it comes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you very new in tensorflow or deep learning. Start reading tutorial from [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners).

Next time if you ask any question, mention more about your problem, like your code. The code you provided is not enough.

But I feel, you must be using stride of 2 or something, in fully connected layer or maxpooling, if you have. It decreases the size of sample and increase the number of neurons.

In you code below, `7 * 7 * 64` is showing that this is length of the flatten 64 neurons of size 7x7.

`1024` is nothing, but just number of neurons in that dense layer.

```
#Densely Connected Layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
```

Comment: Actually I cannot understand the method that works inside densely connected network.

Comment: Densely Connected Layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([16 * 16 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 16*16*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
I found this here:https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros
Thank you @Akhilesh

Comment: `Actually I cannot understand the method that works inside densely connected network.`

Actually, the method that works inside hidden layer is **matrix convolution and addition** and inside dense layer is **matrix multiplication and addition**.

Comment: @SKASIFALI, if you think the answer is helpful, then accept it as a answer or up-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

the original image size is 28*28, after twice 2*2 pooling operation (28/2)/2 =7, the output size of image is 7*7, 64 is the number of filters